# How can I use yup validationSchema with react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form library and yup to validate input fields :

```
const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm({
        mode: 'onBlur',
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            name: Yup.string().max(6, 'Max 6 chars').required('Required boy'),
            pass: Yup.string().min(6, 'Min 6 chars').required('Required boy')
        })
    });

    const submit = (e) => {
        alert(e.name + ' ' + e.pass);
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>

                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" ref={register} />
                {errors.name && <div>{errors.name.message}</div>}

                <input id="pass" type="password" name="pass" ref={register} />
                {errors.pass && <h3>{errors.pass.message}</h3>}

                <button type="submit">Submit</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    );
```

It doesn't throw an error in the console and it alerts when I click submit button but the validation doesn't work at all .

I expect the error message to show up when the input is touched and the value is less or more than the required value .

How can I use yup properly with react-hook-form ?

Comment: Which version of react-hook-forms are you using?

Comment: @EliasSchablowski the latest version and yes it was the version problem , I solved the issue by installing version 4.9.8 .

Comment: @EliasSchablowski Do you know how validation is handled in the latest version ?

Comment: Validation is handled by the [register hook](https://react-hook-form.com/api#register) the `validate` option (there are a couple others, that do simple validation as well but `validate` is the only customizable one).

Comment: @EliasSchablowski So it doesn't support yup library for validation ?

Comment: Not directly, but you can write your own wrapper around `yup` that is compatible with the `validate` option. (e.g. `async value => fieldSchema.isValid(value)`) - Although for your use case you can also use the `minLength` and `maxLenghth` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by installing version 4.9.8

Answer (score 2):

You can use the latest version without downgrading it to 4.9.8

The documentation is in advance section of react hook form under "Custom Hook with Resolver"
https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage

my sample code  below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-yup-material-ui-8ino9

Answer (score 0):

```
phone: yup.string().length(11,'11 digit require').required().label('Phone'),
```